# what to choose from OPENID and SAML 2.0

Tags: c#, openid, saml-2.0

I am new to both Open ID and SAML and need your help to choose right single sign on from both.

My application have users from different domains like

> abc@testdomain.com
> ,xyz@xyzdomain.com

etc.

which would be better for my application ?, please suggest.

i have tried searching internet but not able to find side by side differences.
Also any demo or references to implement it with .NET C# MVC would helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My view:

- SAML - complicated XML based protocol for enterprise domain
- Open ID - easy to implement, because a lot of libs/tools + it's a standard SSO option for many current apps/identity providers (Google, LinkedIn, GitHub)

If you don't need to support SAML, then use Open ID. List of certified libs (C# is there as well) http://openid.net/developers/certified/.

Comment: but is openid suitable for my need ? means i have to relay on openid provider right ? or i have to create my own openid provider ?

Comment: Not, you may use Keycloak on top of your user storage. Then you can use and play woth both typea of SSO, because Keycloak supports OIDC and SAML.

Comment: can you please provide more help on this ? i am totally new on this things

Comment: Keycloak is just another IDP. They all allow the same thing e.g. Okta, Auth0, Azure AD, ADFS, identityserver etc. If you need some background, try https://auth0.com/docs

Comment: Dhaval - For OpenID Connect or for SAML you will need an IdP (or, more precisely, your users coming in will need an IdP). Something, somewhere, needs to be able to verify that the guy who says he is "abc@testdomain.com" actually is that person. As others have stated, OIDC is far easier to implement and to maintain, so should be the first choice these days (2019 now).

Answer (score 2):

Yup - SAML for enterprise - OpenID for mobile or "modern authentication".

For C#, use the OWIN OpenID Connect NuGet packages.

If you are using Azure AD, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples).

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that someone somewhere is going to have to actually verify the identity (generally, by asking for and verifying a password) of "abc@testdomain.com" etc. That "someone" in general terms is an Identity Provider or IdP. Second, note that while you specified SAML 2.0, I assume you also mean the current (in 2018 and now) version of OpenID, "OpenID Connect"; the previous OpenID standards (through 1.2) are very different, no longer supported, and would fall below "SAML" in the "should I support it?" rankings.

For the users you are going to support, do they already have an IdP set up? If so, does that IdP **not** support OpenID Connect and **does** support SAML (or one of the various other less-common SSO standards like WS-Trust, CAS, Facebook Connect, Kerberos, etc)? In that case and that case **only**, I would go with SAML.

If there is no current IdP set up, or if there is an IdP and it IdP supports OpenID Connect (OIDC), then I would go with OIDC support first.

Obviously, if there is an IdP set up, *and* they are not planning on or willing to move forward with a newer one, *and* that IdP only supports something "odd" like CAS or Kerberos, you'll have to implement that standard with your service instead of either SAML or OIDC.

Generally, OIDC is gaining a lot more traction faster than SAML. Microsoft (Azure AD, ADFS), Google, Auth0, Ping, and most other leading IdP vendors either solely support OIDC or advise using OIDC. It has large library support in pretty much every language out there. It is an extension of the most commonly-used API authorization framework (OAuth 2.0). It takes very little in terms of care and feeding. If you run into problems setting up OIDC Relying Party support, there are countless current-technology resources available online.

In contrast, SAML is a complex standard that does not have really good library support and tends to rely on technologies you probably don't want to use otherwise (XML for instance). Setting up and maintaining a SAML integration is time consuming especially with regards to keeping certificates in sync and up to date across the systems. In my own personal experience, where you are able to find help on setting up SAML it will often be outdated (not because SAML itself has changed, but because everything around it has), so you need to be able to translate instructions for, ex, Windows 2008, to whatever you are actually using today. In general, SAML has all the hallmarks of a declining technology.

That having been said, SAML is still widely used in some areas, especially large companies or institutions (ex, colleges) who made a large investment in SAML 10+ years back and aren't looking to redo that investment. If you are working with them, you have few other choices.